# Could not find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration]

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, updating

When upgrading from springboot1.5.x to 2.3.x, it prompts that could not find class [org.springframework.boot.bind.RelaxedPropertyResolver]. I introduced spring-boot-autoconfigure of version 2.3.x to fix this problem, and subsequently it prompts that could not  find class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.MultipartAutoConfiguration], which in spring-boot-autoconfigure of version 1.5.x.

I'm not sure what the problem is - can anyone please help me out? Thanks.

Comment: It would be very helpful if you can share your dependencies, because this type of issue usually occurs when you start mixing versions. Ideally, you should only change the version of `spring-boot-dependencies` or `spring-boot-starter-parent` and all other versions should be managed for you.

Answer (score 0):

RelaxedPropertyResolver errors could arise because of mixed Spring versions. You can do a Maven dependency tree and check for mixed Spring versions (the one of the parent POM and other versions from transitive dependencies. If you have mixed Spring versions in your dependency tree, fix them with dependency management or similar Maven features.

Answer (score 0):

In 2017, this `MultipartAutoConfiguration` class was moved to `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet` package with commit [Restructure web auto-configuration](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/commit/b76ca0bf8f61aafe2f812911f208200c96c4bc69#diff-16a62b1030b7e79d6796fa945ae0a3e127437c3ee6e688e1e33b64f6c753c810)

```
- package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web;
+ package org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet;
```